# Python Unit tests throwing error: ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, unit-testing

I'm trying to create unit tests for my python lambda function, I sctructured the files liek this

```
app/
   locals.py
   lambda_function.py
   tests/
        lambda_function_tests.py
```

On lambda_function.py

```py
from locals import  FOO, FOO2

//code working normally
```

test class

```py
import unittest
from app.locals import FOO, FOO2
from app.lambda_function import lambda_handler
from unittest.mock import patch

class TestLambdaFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_lambda_handler(self):
        event = {}  # Replace with your test event data
        context = {}  # Replace with your test context data
        result = lambda_handler(event, context)
        self.assertIn('statusCode', result)
        self.assertEqual(result['statusCode'], 200)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

But when I try to execute the test, I get the error ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'locals'.... does anyone already faced this error?

**UPDATE**
I added a dot on the imports in the classes that I have functional code BUT when I'll debug the code, got this error ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package

example

```py
from .locals import XPTO
```

instead of

```py
from locals import XPTO
```

Comment: How are you executing your tests? You need to ensure that `app`, not `app/tests`, is added to the module search path.

Comment: The most common mistake with imports is assuming that the current working directory, not the directory that contains the script, is implicitly added to the module search path.

Comment: Do you have an `__init__.py` file in the app folder? If not it won't be found as a python directory

Comment: Can you move tests out of app?

Comment: I made a change here, it works, but IDK if is something that I miss configured
on my lambda_function.py, instead of `from locals import foo` I added a . before, `from .locals import foo`

Comment: @JamieJ yes, I added init as well

Comment: @MarcelWilson unfortunatelly, no, the pipeline will search for tests inside the folder